# How do I disable civicrm.css on public pages in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, css

I have the following in my template.php file, in my custom theme:

```
function shriver_css_alter(&$css) {
    unset($css[drupal_get_path('module','civicrm').'/css/civicrm.css']);
}
```

It doesn't work, though. I can disable other stylesheets this way, but not this one. I know I can disable this stylesheet in civicrm settings, but then it is disabled on the back end as well. I only want it to be disabled on the public pages. Since I use a different admin theme than my public one, I thought it made sense to disable it for my public theme only.

Can someone help me to get this to work? Or, if you know a different method, that would be good, too. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This is the correct way to disable civicrm.css on the front end. Put this in the template.php file of your theme:

function shriver_css_alter(&$css) {
    unset($css['sites/all/modules/civicrm/css/civicrm.css']);
}

Manually enter the path to the css. When I used drupal_get_path('module','civicrm'), it would output sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/css/civicrm.css. Not sure why it added 'drupal' to the path but that was the problem.

Comment: today I tried removing the civicrm css from the public page by adding function shriver_css_alter(&$css) { unset($css['sites/all/modules/civicrm/css/civicrm.css']); } to the themes template.php. Unfortunately it didn't work. The path to the css is the right one. Did something change during the last years?

Comment: Thanks for this, two notes:
1. This snippet hard-codes the file path location of the civicrm module, your location may be different (e.g. sites/default/modules/civicrm).
2. This function works equally well in a module (assuming the module's order is after civicrm).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the CiviCRM Theme module in Drupal Administration menus:

[image: Drupal Modules Menu]

Then, the following menu appears at the bottom of the Drupal Appearance menu:

[image: Allow different themes to be used for front-facing CiviCRM pages]